# JQuery hide()/show() working on FF/IE but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web page in which I use sql/php to create a select where options are in my database : the value of each option is the id on the database.
With this, I use JQuery 3.3.1 : this is the first time I'm using it so I think my syntax might be bad.

First of all there is 2 type of datas : about price and about time.
I made 2 radio button and when the "price" button is checked, the price list is shown while the time list is hidden.

This part of the code works fine on FF/IE/Chrome.

Now I want to display more informations about the option selected so I made a div for every option with style='display:none' and when the option is selected I show the div where the id of the div = the value of the option.

This part of the code works fine on FF/IE but not Chrome.

Here's my code, I replaced database calls by just writing few examples of what I can get here :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "prix") {
            $("#prix").show('fast');
            $("#temps").hide('fast');
            $("#" + $(this).attr("value") + "_prix").siblings().hide('fast');
            $("#" + $(this).attr("value") + "_prix").show('fast');
        }
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "temps") {
            $("#prix").hide('fast');
            $("#temps").show('fast');
            $("#" + $(this).attr("value") + "_temps").siblings().hide('fast');
            $("#" + $(this).attr("value") + "_temps").show('fast');
        }
    });
    $('input[type="radio"]').trigger('click');
});


function showDetailsCriterePrix(id) {
    $("#" + id + "_prix").siblings().hide('fast');
    $("#" + id + "_prix").show('fast');
}

function showDetailsCritereTemps(id) {
    $("#" + id + "_temps").siblings().hide('fast');
    $("#" + id + "_temps").show('fast');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br> Le critère à supprimer concerne le :
<input type="radio" name="cat_critere" value="temps" required>Temps
<input type="radio" name="cat_critere" value="prix" checked required>Prix
<div id="prix" style="display:none">
   <br><br> Choisissez un critère de prix à supprimer :
   <select name="idToDelPrix">
      <option value="1" onclick='showDetailsCriterePrix(this.value);'>Nombre de caisses [AVE] </option>
      <option value="2" onclick='showDetailsCriterePrix(this.value);'>Nombre d'associés [AVE] </option>
      <option value="3" onclick='showDetailsCriterePrix(this.value);'>Nombre de salariés [AVE] </option>
      <option value="4" onclick='showDetailsCriterePrix(this.value);'>Nombre de TVA [AVE] </option>
   </select>
   <div id="wrapperPrix">
      <div id="1_prix" style="display:none"> Taux prix : 175<br> Taux abattement prix : 0<br> Champ obligatoire : Oui</div>
      <div id="2_prix" style="display:none"> Taux prix : 100<br> Taux abattement prix : 0<br> Champ obligatoire : Oui</div>
      <div id="3_prix" style="display:none"> Taux prix : 100<br> Taux abattement prix : 0<br> Champ obligatoire : Oui</div>
      <div id="4_prix" style="display:none"> Taux prix : 1<br> Taux abattement prix : 0<br> Champ obligatoire : Oui</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="temps" style="display:none">
   <br><br> Choisissez un critère de temps à supprimer :
   <select name="idToDelTemps">
      <option value="1" onclick='showDetailsCritereTemps(this.value);'>Temps1 [AVE] </option>
      <option value="2" onclick='showDetailsCritereTemps(this.value);'>Temps2 [AVE] </option>
      <option value="3" onclick='showDetailsCritereTemps(this.value);'>Temps3 [AVE] </option>
      <option value="4" onclick='showDetailsCritereTemps(this.value);'>Temps4 [AVE] </option>
   </select>
   <div id="wrapperTemps">
      <div id="1_temps" style="display:none"> Taux temps : 175<br> Taux abattement temps : 0<br> Champ obligatoire : Oui</div>
      <div id="2_temps" style="display:none"> Taux temps : 100<br> Taux abattement temps : 0<br> Champ obligatoire : Oui</div>
      <div id="3_temps" style="display:none"> Taux temps : 100<br> Taux abattement temps : 0<br> Champ obligatoire : Oui</div>
      <div id="4_temps" style="display:none"> Taux temps : 1<br> Taux abattement temps : 0<br> Champ obligatoire : Oui</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I don't know why this is not working on Chrome, I tried to replace the .click by .change, I tried with and without parameters in hide()/show().

If you guys have any idea it would be very kind !

(Sorry, my code is in French but I think it's understandable even if you don't know French!)

**EDIT** : Answered by [reporter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/326807/reporter) in the comments, thank you very much !

Instead of using show()/hide() we can use toggleClass(). In this case I had to :

1- Create a css class with "display:none;"

2- Replace the style of my divs with this class

[2.5- Add an id to my selects (should have done this before) ]

3- Add an event on my selects that get the value of the selected option and toggle the class of the div with the same id.

4- Remove the now useless showDetailsCriteres functions

Comment: Btw I'm using :
Firefox 59.0.3 ;
Internet Explorer 11 ;
Google Chrome 66 ;

Comment: Why don't you cast `style="display:none"` into a css class and use `toggle(<classname>)` ?

Comment: Didn't thought about it ! Ty I'm trying it rn !

Comment: Works perfectly fine, I'll edit my post to add the working code soon ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply bind onchange event of dropdown rather binding onclick event to each option.

```
     function PrixChange(ctrl){
     var id = $(ctrl).val();
       $("#" + id + "_prix").siblings().hide('fast');
        $("#" + id + "_prix").show('fast');

    }

 <select name="idToDelPrix" onchange="PrixChange(this);">
      <option value="1" onclick='showDetailsCriterePrix(this.value);'>Nombre de caisses [AVE] </option>
      <option value="2" onclick='showDetailsCriterePrix(this.value);'>Nombre d'associés [AVE] </option>
      <option value="3" onclick='showDetailsCriterePrix(this.value);'>Nombre de salariés [AVE] </option>
      <option value="4" onclick='showDetailsCriterePrix(this.value);'>Nombre de TVA [AVE] </option>
   </select>
```

Comment: But in this case I think it's more appropriate to bind onclick event on dropdown : when the list is shown an option is already 'selected' and if you try to select this one no informations will be displayed since onchange doesn't trigger.

Comment: give your dropdown an **id: "idToDelPrix"** and put this line in your document ready: **PrixChange($("#idToDelPrix"));**

Comment: So when the document is ready, this will trigger the function that displays the selected option in the select called **#idToDelPrix** ? Didn't thought about this, ty !

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle class name defining property none. You can try `.on` event instead of `.click` event